# How to execute shell deployment script on Azure Virtual Machine from on premises TFS 2015 release management server?

Tags: powershell, azure, tfs, continuous-deployment, tfs-2015

How to execute power shell deployment script on Azure Virtual Machine from on premises TFS 2015 release management server? 
FYI: AD integration has been already setup for organization, currently office 365 is getting used.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? What research have you done on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

This article provides detailed steps:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/previous-version/deploy-continuously-to-azure

Before you start, you'll need:

- TFS.
- A team project.
- Azure VMs.
- An Azure storage account.
- Release Management for Visual Studio extension. To install in Visual Studio, go to Tools, Extensions and Updates, and search for Release Management for Visual Studio.
- A deployment script.